# Is it possible to test chisel Reg() in console?

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

To test Chisel code, I launch a console sbt then scala in the directory of my project where is the file build.sbt. I can import chisel3 library :

```
$ cd myproject
$ sbt
sbt:myproject> console
scala> import chisel3._
import chisel3._
```

Then I can test some chisel code for data type for example :

```
scala> val plop = "b01010101".U(20.W)
plop: chisel3.UInt = UInt<20>(85)
```

But I can test Reg() or other Module() elements :

```
scala> val plopReg = RegInit(23.U(24.W))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: must be inside Builder context
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
  at chisel3.internal.Builder$.dynamicContext(Builder.scala:232)
  at chisel3.internal.Builder$.currentClock(Builder.scala:308)
  at chisel3.internal.Builder$.forcedClock(Builder.scala:318)
  at chisel3.RegInit$.apply(Reg.scala:155)
  at chisel3.RegInit$.apply(Reg.scala:173)
  ... 36 elided
```

Is there a tips to test these chisel element in console ? Or is it mandatory to write a file code source ?

Comment: You can use them in a console, but you need to instantiate all hardware types (`Reg`, `Wire`, etc) inside a `Module` context. Similar thing is done in https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp using an `ammonite`-compatible shell (almond+jupyter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on here is that `UInt` is a Chisel type while `Reg` is a hardware type.

You can play with hardware types only inside a module. I often do something like the following to play with them on the console:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.{ChiselStage, ChiselGeneratorAnnotation}
import chisel3.util.Cat

import firrtl.EmittedCircuitAnnotation

class Foo extends MultiIOModule {
  val in = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val out = IO(Output(Bool()))

  val tmp = RegNext(~in)

  out := tmp
}

val args = Array(
  "-X", "verilog",
  "-E", "high",
  "-E", "middle",
  "-E", "low",
  "-E", "verilog")

(new ChiselStage).execute(args, Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new Foo)))
```

You can then look at the various outputs inside your `chisel3` top-level directory.

### More Information

What's going on, specifically, is that `UInt` (and things like it) are factory methods that generate classes (technically `UInt` is really an object that extends [`UIntFactory`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/package$$UInt$.html)). When you do `UInt(4.W)`, that's constructing a new `UInt`. You should be able to construct new classes anywhere you want which is why this works on the console.

However, when you do `Reg(UInt(4.W))` that's interacting with global mutable state used during the elaboration process to associate a register with a specific module. This global mutable state is stored inside the `Builder`. The error that you get is coming from the `Builder` where you've tried to use its methods without first being inside a module.